# High voltage (165V) H-bridge design

Tags: circuit-design, high-voltage, h-bridge

I'm trying to design an H-bridge circuit for 165 volts and am having some trouble. The motor I'm driving is actually an AC motor, which is why I'll be switching the signals 60 times per second, with variable offtime to get the motor to the correct speed. This is not where my problem lies however. My problems arise when building the below schematic, I can't get it to work, but it's not a consistent error either, sometimes some MOSFETs stay conducting, sometimes they overheat and sometimes a resistor burns up, it keeps changing. So I was hoping to get some advice from you people as to what might be going wrong. If you'd just look at my schematic, that would be great.

Datasheets: [IRF640](https://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf640.pdf), [IRF9640](http://www.e-ele.net/DataSheet/IRF9640.pdf)

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Are you using a dead times during switching polarities?

Comment: You need good isolated gate drivers, some sort of supply of 12v to the gate drivers, like boost l diode and capacitor. It's not complicated, but you really need to read the manuals for a bit. Look at Ti's evaluation board designs.

Comment: At first glance the switch-on time for the p-channel FETs may be rather slow, do they remain in the safe operating area while switching or are you relying on near-instantaneous switching?  I haven’t looked at the specs in detail but it looks like switching may take a few milliseconds

Comment: More importantly, you need much more than 60Hz. What you need is 10kHz modulated with 60Hz.

Comment: I'm not particularly thrilled with the slow gate drive, but at low frequencies, it indeed might not matter. The answer doesn't seem to be on the schematic shown. Therefore, please edit your post to add information around this schematic: what are `Signal1` and `Signal2`? What is `+165V` sourced from?

Comment: Signal1 and Signal2 are 5V and come from a microcontroller. The +165V comes from a rectified AC 105V line. There's also a 680uF capacitor between the rectifier output and this circuit's +165V line. Glad to hear there's nothing wrong with the schematic though.
As someone who is quite new to this, could you explain to me why the MOSFET gate drive is slow?

Comment: Your schematic is hard to read. Please follow normal schematic convention and draw all positive voltages pointing up, ground and negative pointing down. Q2 and Q8 are “upside down”. Turn-off of Q1 and Q4 will be very slow due to the diodes on the gate. Place a resistor in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed some completing data:
What is the DC resistance of the AC motor?
Its nominal current at operation? Full mechanical and without any load)

Anyway, I assume the motor is something like 500 W or more, with DC resistance of 30 Ohms or less.

D9 and D12 make me think that signals should be something around 12 to 15 Volts.
**But Signal1 and Signal2 are 5 V** and so will be UGS of Q1 and Q4 - even less due D10 and D11 (and R12/R11, R13/R14)!
UGS can be something around 4.5 V - due to Fig. 1 and Fig. 2 of IRF640 - it is *typical* to have ca. 0.5 A at 1V UDS at 25°C, even heated up to 150°C (Fig. 2) it will have ca. 2 A at 1 V UDS - your motor probably pulls more, so it will end up with more than 2.5 A at more than 50 V --> more than 100 W, no wonder the MOSFETs burn/overheat.
All values above are typical, so some MOSFET may be better!
Summarized - **you operate the Q1 and Q4 in bad/worst operation areas** with UGS = ca. 4.5 V or even less!

And the 5V signal is really 5V? Depending on the logic family the High can be as low as 2 V for TTL!

You definitely need a level shifter that amplifies the 0 and 5V to 0 and 12 V!

Additionally you need a push **and pull** driver before the signal1 and signal2 connectors. So remove D10 and D11 (and D9 and D12 are not needed with a 12 V supply).
Why?
The MOSFETs have a parasite capacitance between Gate and Source of 1.3 nF (typical only!) at 0 V UGS.
So the discharge time with R12 or R14 gives 15 k * 1.3 nF = ca. 20 us time constant. That means at switching off the MOSFET the UGS will fall slowly to 0 V and passes some critical areas, where ID and UDS of the MOSFET are producing a lot of power loss. That it could be damaged.

The high side (Q2 and Q8) will switch on and off slowly/ier too - as some commenters mentionned.
To build a pull push driver for their gates with 12 V supply is even more effort.

Instead you could use more signals signal3 for Q2, signal4 for Q8, that have time delay to signal1 and signal2 instead.
In such a manner that the slowly switching Q2 and Q8 ocurrs only if both Q1 and Q4 are completely switched off.
Then only Q1 and Q4 have to be switched on and off with good push-pull driver by 12 V power supply.
In this case the range of PWM will be limited due to the waiting times for Q2 and Q8 completely switching off and on respectively.